# Can't run Visual Web Gui application into windows azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, visual-web-gui

the problem is after I publish my webGui application and then show me this message:
"403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied."

what I have to change in the webconfig to make runnable this app?

Comment: This isn't an azure problem but an ASP.NET one - try searching for that error message for ASP.NET...

Answer (score 0):

Check if you set the handlers rights, you should have one handler for *.wgx pointing to

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
```

Concerning the Error 403, try to check if you can see a simple .html file, maybe it is a folder permit and you have to enable IIS service to be able to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have to manually FTP my web.config file to my azure web server.  I don't understand why the deployment doesn't update it successfully, but I can see that it doesn't by logging into the server via FTP and downloading the web config after I deploy.

Once I copied up the appropriate web.config, everything worked perfectly.